# How to set KUBE_ENABLE_INSECURE_REGISTRY=true on a running Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I forgot to set export `KUBE_ENABLE_INSECURE_REGISTRY=true` when running `kube-up.sh` (AWS provider). I was wondering if there was anyway to retroactively apply that change to a running cluster. It is only a 3 node cluster so doing it manually is an option. Or is the only way to tear down the cluster and start from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but in theory you just need to add `--insecure-registry 10.0.0.0/8` (if you are running your insecure registry in the kube network `10.0.0.0/8`) to the docker daemon options (`DOCKER_OPTS`).

You can also specify the url instead of the network.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I need to set DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry 10.0.0.0/8 on each node? Just on the master? In what file?

Comment: On each node, as when you create a pod, it uses the local docker to pull the image. 

The `10.0.0.0/8` is because I supposed that you are running the registry inside kubernetes. If that it's not the case, you should add the one that you are using. For example, if you are using `registry.mycompany.com:5000` you should use:

`DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry registry.mycompany.com:5000`.

I hope it helps

Comment: Ok, I just don't understand where I should write the DOCKER_OPTS... in a file on the node filesystem?

Comment: Yes, depending on the OS you are using. In ubuntu is `/etc/default/docker`